# Найти совпадение из двух массивов Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Есть два массива

```
["Hello. This is line 1 of text.", "and this is another.", "the end", "line 3 here"]


["the end", "matches", "line 3", "and this is anoother."]
```

Нужно вывести,если есть совпадение где то в строке.

результат должен быть:

```
 ['line 3 here','the end','and this is another.']
```

Comment: Почему `'line 3 here'`? Опечатка?

Comment: @AlexeyTen  да, исправил

Comment: попробуйте библиотеку lodash метод intersection: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#intersection

Comment: И всё таки... Строка `line 3 here` имеется в обеих массивах?

Comment: @XelaNimed нет, только в первой.

Comment: В этом случае по какой логике необходимо получить результат? В приведённом Вами результате первый элемент есть только в первом массиве, второй элемент и в первом, и во втором...

Comment: @XelaNimed искал чтоб по словам тоже. Например line 3 и в первом и на втором же, из за этого так

Comment: @РустамГимранов да должен попасть по идее. исправил

Comment: Получается каждое словосочетание на слова разбивается и уже по этим словам поиск совпадений?

Comment: @РустамГимранов да так. Внизу пример только по строкам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте комбинацию из [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) и [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
var arr1 = ["Hello. This is line 1 of text.", "and this is another.", "the end", "line 3 here"],
    arr2 = ["the end", "matches", "line 3 here", "and this is another."],
    intersect = function(arr1, arr2) {
      return arr1.filter(function(n) {
        return arr2.indexOf(n) !== -1;
      });
    };

console.log(intersect(arr1, arr2));
```

#### Ссылки по теме

- [Array​.prototype​.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)
- [Array​.prototype​.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 1):

Решение на чистом javascript

```js
var first = ["Hello. This is line 1 of text.", "and this is another.", "the end", "line 3 here"];
var second = ["the end", "matches", "line 3", "and this is anoother."]; 

for (var i = 0; i < first.length; i++) { //проходимся по первому масиву
  for (var j = 0; j< second.length; j++) { // ищем соотвествия во втором массиве
    if(first[i] === second[j]){
      console.log(first[i]); // если совпадаем делаем что либо с этим значением
    }
  }
}
```